# Why doesnt '?' work here with from_str_radix

Tags: rust

(my first rust project - please be patient)

I have an octal string, I want to make a u16 and pass it to a function.
the function

```
fn expand_rkda(val : u16){
    println!("RKDA:{}", val);
}
```

I try

```
let z = u16::from_str_radix(rval, 8);
  match rname.as_str() {
        "rkda" => expand_rkda(z),
        _ => println!("oops")
    }
```

this errors as

```
17 |         "rkda" => expand_rkda(z),
   |                               ^ expected `u16`, found enum `std::result::Result`
```

I went - aha , I know this , its to do with result type and I recall there is a nice quick ? I can use (I read the book)

So I changed to

```
let z = u16::from_str_radix(rval, 8)?;
```

And now I get

```
14 | |     let z = u16::from_str_radix(rval, 8)?;
   | |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
```

Comment: Read the entire error message: "this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`"

Comment: @mcarton doesnt the first error say that from_str_radix is returning a Result? I means the docs say thats what it returns https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.from_str_radix

Comment: But the calling function must return a `Result` too. `?` is meant to propagate errors.

Comment: @mcarton aha - i thought it would panic

Comment: @mcarton its a very misleading error. underlining a function call and saying 'this function...' not meaning the function underlined.. TY. Make it an answer please

Answer (score 0):

as mcarton points out. In order to use ? in a function anywhere that function itself must return a Result. And my main was not doing that